# How to extend primitive types in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to extend the `number` primitive in TypeScript by adding a `clamp` method. I tried doing this:

```
declare global {
    interface Number {
        clamp(min: number, max: number): number
    }
}

Number.prototype.clamp = function(min, max): number {
    return Math.min(Math.max(this, min), max);
};
```

At this point I expected to be able to use it on `number` variables, but my IDE (WebStorm 2021.1.3) was already pointing out issues:

`TS2345: Argument of type 'Number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'. 'number' is a primitive, but 'Number' is a wrapper object. Prefer using 'number' when possible.`

After reading this, I tried changing `interface Number` to `interface number`, but was met with `TS2427: Interface name cannot be 'number'.`

So I reverted my changes and slapped a `@ts-ignore` in the erroring line of the clamp implementation and tried to use it... however:

```
let x: number = 10;
x.clamp(0, 5);  // TS2339: Property 'clamp' does not exist on type 'number'.
```

What gives? How does one properly extend primitive types in TypeScript?

Comment: This is not recommended and a bad practice to modify.

Comment: @xdeepakv I was missing the last step from this thread. Importing the file fixed my last issue, but I am still getting the first warning (TS2345). As for why this is not recommended and bad practice, can I ask why? What would be the best practice in this case? Just declare the function in a library as opposed to extending the primitive?